# Prism - windows store App 8.1 - screen resolution from viewmodel

Tags: xaml, mvvm, windows-store-apps, prism

I need getting screen resolution from my Viewmodel.
I have a grid

```
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"  MaximumRowsOrColumns="{Binding MaxRow}" ItemHeight="200" ItemWidth="400"  ></VariableSizedWrapGrid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>                
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

In the viewModel, the property MaxRow depends the screen resolution, and i don't know how to perform this in a "clean way".

Comment: Use dependency injection.

Comment: I had not thought about that. Good idea.